# Android In App BIlling v3 doesn't work Nexus 7

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app which uses the new v3 of in app billing and it all works great on multiple devices. The only exception is the Nexus 7 which when trying to initialize the helper as per Google's documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), reports the error:

```
12-12 20:26:43.769: E/EnvironmentMainActivity(15324): Problem setting up In-app Billing: IabResult: Error checking for billing v3 support. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
```

This happens on 2 different Nexus 7 which each have completely separate user accounts on them. Both devices have build 3.10.9 of the play store, the same as all the other Nexus devices I tested on which work perfectly. Given the recent nature of v3 of the library, there is little more than the press about the release online. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Check the version of Google Play Services on your devices. It *seems* it depends on it as well, although the functionality is in the Play store app.

Comment: Cf. this by Google's Ian Ni-Lewis: 'IABv3 is built into Google Play services, so it requires an update to the Play Services apk. V2 was built into the Play store client itself. The cache/EULA issue isn't specifically related to IAB, it's related to setting up Play Services (and hopefully is unnecessary for most users, the cache part anyway). It's a bummer to be in this transition period where Play Services has to be updated before your app can take advantage of it, but I think most people would agree that it's better than waiting for an OS upgrade.'

Comment: BTW, latest GPS is 2.0.12: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Clear the cache and data of the Google Play Store, then start the Google Play Store at least once.

Comment: Fixed billing not being supported, however now it says it cant find the item. Ill make a new question for that in the morning, as this technically does solve the original question.

Comment: Turns out that error was caused by me changing my package name so it didn't match with google play. Minor oversight caused by too much coding. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch the original question was solved by this answer. The oversight was related to not finding the item which was unrelated to the original issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem when i run code on device that is **not logged in Google Play Store.**
Change device, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks - this was the issue for me. The test device was not signed in with a Google account